# How do i get multiple values in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, count

I'm stuck in loop.

I have a postgres database and i have to filter  the top-5, unique co-author pairs by number of jointly published papers.

I want to return pairs of author names and paper count

[image: SQL Schema]

What i have so far:

```
select persons.name as person, count(papers.pkey) as amount 
from persons 
  inner join authpapers on authpapers.akey = persons.akey 
  inner join papers on authpapers.pkey = papers.pkey  
group by persons.name 
order by amount desc limit 5;
```

As a result i get the first 5 authors ba name and paper count but i want papers where an author had a co author.

Comment: If GMB's answer solved your problem (i assume that's the case because of your comment) you can affirm that by accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the `persons` table to generate authors combinations, then bring each person's papers by joining `authpapers` once per user, and finally filter on matching papers. The final step is aggregation and sorting:

```
select p1.name as person1, p2.name person2, count(*) as amount
from persons p1
inner join persons p2 on p2.akey > p1.akey
inner join authpapers ap1 on ap1.akey = p1.akey 
inner join authpapers ap2 on ap2.akey = p2.akey 
where ap1.pkey = ap2.pkey
group by p1.akey, p2.akey
order by amount desc limit 5;
```

Note that you don't need the `papers` table to get the results that you want.